# Dynamic inputs for every day of month

Tags: php, laravel, input

Input for every day in the month:

[image: Input for every day in the month]

I'm using PHP Laravel and I need to make dynamic inputs for every day of the month, like in the image. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you're asking other people to write your code without even trying yourself, but here we go.

Laravel uses Carbon, a simple PHP API extension for PHP DateTime.

First you have to check which month you're currently in, and when you've done that, you can run the Carbon method called `daysInMonth` on the Carbon instance to return the amount of days in the month of the current date.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$currentDate = Carbon::now();

$daysInMonth = $currentDate->daysInMonth);

return view('your.view', compact('daysInMonth');
```

Now you have the amount of days in the current month. Simple, just run a for loop while `i` is equal or smaller than the `$daysInMonth`.

That will look like the following:

```
@for($i = 1; $i =< $daysInMonth; $i++)
    <input type="text" name="day[]" value="$i">
@endfor
```

[Carbon docs](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: Thank  you Liam, you give me a light!!